# Outputting a simple board game on Elixir, but a variable is not decrementing. How to fix this?

Tags: variables, for-loop, elixir, decrement

I have a function called main(row,col) that will take 2 integers and put them into row and col respectively. Then it will create an output of a board, so main(2,3) will create a 2 by 3 board.

```
spaces= row*col
```

so in this case, spaces=6 and SHOULD decrement by 1 each time i create a cell. However it does not do this. My output when I run this is

```
 Main.main(2,3)
+---+---+---+
|  6|  6|  6|
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|  6|  6|  6|
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
```

I need it to be

```
 Main.main(2,3)
+---+---+---+
|  6|  5|  4|
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|  3|  2|  1|
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
```

Here is my code:

```
defmodule Main do

  def main(row,col) do
    spaces = row*col

    for i <- 0..(row-1) do
      for j <- 0..(col-1) do
        if j == 0 do
          IO.write "+"
        end 

        IO.write "---+"
      end
      IO.puts ""
      columns = col

      for columns <- 1..columns do
        if columns == 1 do
          IO.write "|"
        end

        if spaces < 10 do
          IO.write "  "
          IO.write spaces
          IO.write "|"
        else if spaces < 100 do
          IO.write " "
          IO.write spaces
          IO.write "|"
        end

        if spaces > 99 do
          IO.write spaces
          IO.write "|"
        end
        spaces = (spaces - 1) 
      end
    end
    IO.puts ""
    columns = col
    for columns <- 1..columns do
      if columns == 1 do
        IO.write "|"
      end
      IO.write"   |"
    end

    IO.puts ""
    if i == row-1 do
      botside = col
      for botside <- 1..col do
        if botside == 1 do
          IO.write "+"
        end
        IO.write "---+"
      end
    end
  end
end

end
```

as you can see,

```
 spaces =(spaces - 1)
```

is not decrementing for whatever reason.. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: You need to let go of thinking in terms of mutability.  Elixir is a functional language which means you can't do destructive assignment e. g. `spaces = (spaces - 1)`

Comment: You would be better creating lists up front and then manipulating them. One list for the cell labels; another for the row numbers, and another for the columns.  Then zip them together. Then use Elixir excellent List, Enum, or Stream modules to create the board you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I mean by creating the lists first

```
rows=3
cols=2
top = rows*cols

labels = Enum.to_list top..1  # [6,5,4,3,2,1]

c = Enum.to_list 1..rows # [1,2,3]
c = List.duplicate c, cols # [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
c = List.flatten c   # [1,2,3,1,2,3]

r = Enum.to_list 1..cols # [1,2]
r = List.duplicate r, rows #[[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]
r = List.flatten r   # [1,2,1,2,1,2]

list = List.zip( [r, c, labels] )

board = list |> Enum.each( fn {r,c,label} -> print_cell r,c, label, rows, cols end)

defp print_cell r,c, label, rows,cols do
 # your conditional cases for each edge case here
end
```

Comment: This is a perfect use case for a comprehension :) `r = for _ <- 1..cols, row <- 1..rows, do: row  #⇒ [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]`.

Comment: @ mudasobwa : true -- it's all about how readable it makes it for you, yourself

Comment: Tysm for your help. It's time to look at a tutorial for Enums since everyone keeps mentioning it and I have no clue what it is. Seems useful though.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
spaces = (spaces - 1)
```

being put inside a comprehension does not do what you expect. It declares new local variable `spaces` as outermost `spaces` minus one. This local variable `spaces`, despite it has the same name as the outermost variable, dies when comprehension is ended.

The whole code is as non-elixir-idiomatic, that it’s hard to suggest any elegant solution here. In general, states are to be avoided in Elixir.

As a kludge here one might use:

```
spaces = spaces + 1 - columns
```

Answer (score 0):

As @mudasobwa points out, it's hard to tell you how to fix this because it's so fundamentally contrary to the way things are usually done in functional programming.

That said, here's an example of one way you could implement a decrementing loop in Elixir:

```
 defmodule Test do
   def decrementing_loop(initval) do
         IO.inspect initval
         if (initval > 0) do
           decrementing_loop(initval-1)
         end
   end
 end
```

Except you'd probably want to pass a function to `decrementing_loop`--like so:

```
defmodule Test do
  def decrementing_loop(initval, f) do
    f.(initval)
    if (initval > 0) do
      decrementing_loop(initval - 1, f)
    end
  end
end
```

Which would then be called like so:

```
Test.decrementing_loop(10,&IO.inspect/1)
```

The point is that I'm not actually modifying `initval`  Instead I'm passing a new argument of the current `initval-1` to a recursive call to the function.

All that said, IMHO if you're serious about learning Elixir, you'd be wise to invest in a good book rather than trying to nibble at pieces of it by asking a series of questions here.